# CakePHP Issue : Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp

I have looked on here and found some people having some of the same problems but none of there solutions seemed to work for me.

Now I am trying to add a new page into a website I have been given to update (I did not start the site form new, myself). Now with the same table(s) has what is in my live site, I use this code with a new copy of cakePHP. However I get 'Call to a member function find() on a non-object' and this might, i think, have something to do with the way i am calling the find command or the way cakePHP config file might have been changed.

Add this to my Routes.php :

```
         Router::connect('/events', array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'eventDetails'));
```

My Model code :

```
   class Event extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Event';

var $validate = array(
    'id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'startdate' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'endate' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'spaces' => array(
        'alphanumeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('alphanumeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'info' => array(
        'alphanumeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('alphanumeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'info' => array(
        'alphanumeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('alphanumeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'img' => array(
        'alphanumeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('alphanumeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
);
//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

var $belongsTo = array(
    'Team' => array(
        'className' => 'Team',
        'foreignKey' => 'team_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
);
}
```

This code points, and i think checks all my db fields, this is code I copied from another model but changed it for the use with my table.

My Controller Code :

```
class EventsController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Events';
var $uses = array();

function eventDetails() {

    $EventData = $this->Event->find('all');

    print_r($EventData);


    die();      
} //End of function eventDetails()

 } // End of EventsController Class
```

Screen Error :

```
        Notice (8): Undefined property: EventsController::$Event        [APP/controllers/events_controller.php, line 10] Fatal error: Call to a member function   find() on a non-object in /var/www/vh/app/controllers/events_controller.php on line 10
```

The only two table this deals with are events & teams - They are saved as lower case, and with 's' at the end. The teams table was already in the db, events table is the new I made. Like I say when I use these table, exported from the live site, to a test db, then using a new CakePHP setup, is works, it prints the tables contents.

So It must be something to do with the way CakePHP is setup and this (cake) is still very new to me. This is the 1s time I have ever made a new model/controller/table. All I have been doing is adding new functions to already built & working controllers.

I have also tried this code, '$EventData = $this->set('events', $this->Event->find('all'));' I got '$this->set('events'' from another post on this type of error

I have tried to be as clear as possible, please let me know if I have not been.

Many Thanks For Any Help!

Glenn Curtis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
var $uses = array();
```

CakePHP has it's own inheritance model. As such, `$uses` is rather counterintuitive.

```
$uses = array('Event', 'Foo'); // explicitly use Event and Foo model
$uses = array(); // don't use any models
```

By default, CakePHP implicitly sets `$uses` to the corresponding model of the controller, in your case `Event`. So simply removing it is the *Cake* way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I do that (remove the var $uses) and the default view (?) loads, i think. It just seems to pass over my 'die()' command! Also, give me 'An Internal Error Has Occurred Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred' within the default view layout.

Comment: Are you visiting `/events/eventDetails`? Sounds like you have more than one problem.

Comment: I think I am, as I go to -> 'localhost/site/events' and I have a route set up to pass me over to the eventDetails function, or is that wrong?

Comment: Looks like the problem stated in the question is answered, this answer should be accepted...

Comment: I'd try visiting the URI I mentioned. Also, as noted by **Hoff**, this answers the original question, you should post a new question if you are having *more* problems.

Comment: I am not sure, I think this is the same problem. Removing the var $uses, and the site just loads to a default error page, which does not make any sense as i have a die command in my function, which its just by passing. So your saying by removing the var call, its working. Then how comes it does not print my find command on the screen and bypassing my die? I can post this is a new questions if you think that is best.

Comment: There's the argument that the code never worked to begin with. Either way, removing `var $uses = array();` is definitely *part* of the solution. Obviously from the fact that you are no longer seeing the *error*. New *error* means new *problem* :)

Comment: I did post a new question for this new problem like you guys said. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754710/cakephp-display-error/11756641#11756641

I just thought I let anyone who wanted to know what was wrong with my setup. I solved it! It was my debug level, it had been changed to 0 and in my new copy of cake it was 2. So when I changed it, it started to use my code, e.g my die command. 

Many Thanks for all your help, Glenn Curtis