# CakePHP Display Error

Tags: cakephp

My last post can be found here,

[CakePHP Issue : Call to a member function find() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744407/cakephp-issue-call-to-a-member-function-find-on-a-non-object)

I am asking a new question, as the people who answered my last question, said that the error I am getting now is a new problem, therefore a new post.

Please read my last post, if any of you wish me to re-post all my code on this post I will do so, just ask!

So my problem is that, yes once I do remove the vars $uses from my code, it works in the NEW copy of cake I have put on the same server. However it just bypasses my die command when I use it on my live site! Now I know (or at lest think) this must be something to do with the way this copy of cake was configured.

Also, in the NEW copy of cake I did not have to add a 'Router' path in the routes.php file for it to work. However on the live site, it will just give me a 404 error when trying to access the controller. Now with the NEW copy of cake, I called the function index(), but in the live site I named it eventDetails(), now I have tried changing this to index(), but I still get a 404 error when the router path is not there and the same 'Internal Error Has Occurred', see last post.

Any ideas?

Again any help would be very welcome.

Glenn Curtis.

Comment: Sounds like you either don't have routes setup properly or you've misnamed something - a controller file name, class name maybe. Be sure to check these.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am sure this is not the case. I have taken these files and used them in a new copy of cake, that works. But I have checked, 'table name : events', all lowercase. 'model name : event.php' - 'controller name : events_controller'. I think that is right. Moving from event to events is sometimes I little hard to know where you stand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks For your help Dunhamzz.

But I have solved the issue. I knew it was something to do with my set-up and the guy who set-up this cake site set the debug level to 0. While the new copy of cake had it set to 2.

Thanks

Glenn.